# How to get blog result list into catalog search Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, search, catalogsearch

Hello I am currently working on Custom blog extension. Where I want to get blog posts in catalog result.

where I am having my_blog_post table with following columns.

1. id
2. title
3. image
4. description
5. publish_time
6. update_time